# import sklearn fails despite using pip3 install in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Have tried following steps in sequence:

1. cmd prompt :

> pip3 install sklearn

shows

> requirement already satisfied. sklearn and scikit-learn directories
> get printed

2. Spyder code editor :

> import sklearn as sk_learn. Result : ModuleNotFoundError: No module
> named 'sklearn'

**Windows 10. Further details below:**

```
C:\Users\X360>pip3 install sklearn
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\users\x360\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\x360\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from sklearn) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\x360\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in c:\users\x360\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\x360\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\x360\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.19.3)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\x360\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Did you tried doing `pip3 install scikit-learn`?

Comment: Did that in cmd. Still , am getting the modulenotfound.                             
C:\Users\X360>pip3 install scikit-learn

Comment: Have checked using C:\Users\X360>python -m pip show. All the packages scikit-learn scipy threadpoolctl numpy joblib are downloaded in valid locations. Yet importing sklearn within Spyder does not work.

Answer (score 1):

`sklearn` is the shortcut of `scikit-learn`. You should try:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

> choose pip/pip3 depending to your working enviroment

See the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) for further information

Also there is a warning about your pip version, i suggest you to update your pip via

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```